# Two problems with decimal alignment in tables: null entries and changing color

Tags: tables, color

Output table from the MWE:

[image: Sample table with problems]

Problems:

1) When the color of the numeric values are changed we also want the color of the decimal point to change.

2) We want the null entry (last entry in column 1) to be an empty field; instead the alignment character `.` appears.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{r@{.}lr@{.}l}
      \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & 3 & 1 \\
      2 & 1 & 4 & 4 \\
      &&      5 & 7
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Distribution: TeXLive - 2015

Application: TeXShop 3.58

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `siunitx` package, you will have a much simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

  \begin{table}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.5]S[table-format=-1.1]}
      \color{red}1.0 & 3.1 \\
      2.12346 & -4.4 \\
      & 5.7
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer looks great. However when the second row is replaced with `2.12346 & -4.4`  disaster results. Can we restore the flexibility of `r@{.}l`?

Comment: Yes of course.. You have to specify the ‘maximum’  format in each column, as an optional argument to the `S` column type. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: What a great solution. Much easier to use.